# Bash case in using variable that is piped wildcard values

Tags: bash, wildcard, case-insensitive, case-statement

```
CONDITION="*boss*|*mwc*|*puppet*|*nexus*"

case in ${myvar1}
      ${CONDITION} )
        echo HIT
        ;;
      * )
        echo MISS
        ;;
esac
```

I have couple of issues with this:

1. Above code does not work
2. I want insensitive matches to be hit, eg. "Boss1234" or "system MWc", at the moment I know I can do eg. CONDITION="*[mM][wW][cC]*" but that is not very useful for longer strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `shopt -s extglob` to enable `extglob` shell option
change the condition:

```
CONDITION="@(*boss*|*mwc*|*puppet*|*nexus*)"
```

The correct case syntax:

```
case ${myvar1} in
      ${CONDITION} )
        echo HIT
        ;;
      * )
        echo MISS
        ;;
esac
```

Comment: +1 Here, the `@` operator provides a sort of indirection for the pattern alternation.

Comment: sorry that was typo in above code of course it has to be "case $var in", your code works fine! Thanks 
The only remaining issue is the case sensitivity, but that does not bother me so much and was this. Thanks again!